# Javascript comparing 2 checks for localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, comparison, local-storage

I saw this in the diveintohtml5 website. This is how they check to see if localstorage is supported on the browser.

`return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;`

Would this be the same as just doing?

`return window.localStorage != undefined`

Comment: personally I would do do `return !!window.localStorage` which would convert the values of `0,false,undefined,"",NaN` to a false to do a better check

Comment: @Robert I think `return typeof window.localStorage == 'object';` is the best method. If the localStorage property is not an object, then that means that it's not implemented in the browser

Comment: +1, this would be better as its more strict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1**

```
return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
```

This returns true if the `window` object contains a property with the name `localStorage` and the value of that property is not `null`.

---

**2**

```
return window.localStorage != undefined
```

This returns true if the `window` object contains a propety with the name `localStorage` and the value of that property is not `undefined` or `null`
(I am assuming that the global property `undefined` holds the value `undefined`)

Comment: Your analysis points out that the 2nd test is better since the first would return true if someone set `window.localStorage = undefined`

Comment: @Šime One problem: `typeof null === 'object'` so if window.localStorage is null you will report true.

Comment: @Hemlock Yes, of course. It has to be like so then: `return typeof window.localStorage == 'object' && window.localStorage != null;` This will check whether or not the localStorage property is an object.

Comment: As already told by Hemlock, `return typeof window.localStorage != 'undefined';` works incorrectly. When browser supports localStorage, but it's disabled by user, window.localStorage has value of null; and given check returns true (which is not correct).

Answer (score 5):

Same *result* anyhow since if `window.localStorage` is `undefined` you will both get `false`. And if `window.localStorage` is null you will both get `false` because `undefined == null`.

However, I prefer using `!!` just because it's the fastest way to convert to a boolean and how useful is localStorage if it's false, null, undefined, '', NaN or 0?

```
return !!window.localStorage;
```

**Edit**
One caveat, they are not exactly the same since if you set `window.localStorage` to `undefined` the first would report it as `true`

Comment: +1 as i have just written the same in the comments before i noticed your answer :)

Comment: @Hemlock If the localStorage property exists but has the value undefined, then the first snippet returns true, but the second snippet returns false.

Comment: @Hemlock But how useful is localStorage if it's a string, or a number, or the boolean value true, ... Therefore, since we really want to check whether it is implemented in the browser or not, I believe this to be the best check in this particular case: `return typeof window.localStorage == 'object';`

Comment: +1 Ah, good points (about the edit and the conversion). I was under the impression setting a property to undefined is the same as deleting the key from the object. I tested it, its not. And I didn't know `!!` was the fastest way to convert to boolean. Thanks for that too. I am going to mark Sime's answer as correct, because as he says, the type check of object is probably what I really want.

Comment: @Šime I think you missed the point. The point is, by testing too broadly using `!!` you don't really miss out on anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) (1.1 or later) to detect support for HTML5 local storage.

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
  // window.localStorage is available
} else {
  // no support for local storage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish you to recommend the following function:

```
function getLocalStorage(){
   if (typeof localStorage == “object”){
      return localStorage;
   } else if (typeof globalStorage == “object”){
      return globalStorage[location.host];
   } else {
      throw new Error(“Local storage not available.”);
   }
}
```

1. First check will be enough to make sure localStorage is availabe
2. Some browsers still don't support local storage, but global storage. It has the same function set, but has some differences comparing with localStorga
3. If none of storages is supported, throw exception.

If you want to read about global storage, compare it with local storage, Look at "JavaScript for Web Developers", chapter 19. It describes client local storages, comparing it with cookies.