# How can I detect if Windows local storage is available?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using the following code:

```
//if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
//    // window.localStorage is available!
//} else {
//    // document.location.href = '/Error/Message/OldBrowser';
//}
```

Is there some way that I can do the same thing without the overhead of using Modernizr?

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706347/javascript-comparing-2-checks-for-localstorage

Comment: Exactly how much overhead is Modernizr if you only include that one test? Anyway, you can just copy the test in the Modernizr source: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js#L779

Comment: I would rely on modernizr as it will deal with browser evolution. And it is so small in size that you may afford it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if browser supports HTML5 Local Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214404/how-to-detect-if-browser-supports-html5-local-storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!!window.localStorage) {
   /* you have localstorage */
}
```

note: localstorage is natively available even on IE8

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the !!   Thanks

Comment: (!!) double not, it coerces the expression as a boolean

Answer (score 1):

From DevProConnections magazine:

```
function supportStorage()
{
    return ('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] != null;
}
```