# Is Web Storage enabled by default on supported browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage, web-storage, browser-support

Given this [support chart](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage), can I assume that all the supporting browsers listed there enable this feature *by default*?

If not, what would be the simplest way to check if `SessionStorage` is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!window.sessionStorage)`

or

`if (!("sessionStorage" in window))`

[How can I detect if Windows local storage is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777599/how-can-i-detect-if-windows-local-storage-is-available)

[HTML5 Local Storage fallback solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions)

http://24ways.org/2009/breaking-out-the-edges-of-the-browser

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills  --> Web Storage