# localStorage alerts undefined but if undefined is false

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Can not quite understand the reasoning for this. In the following code the `localStorage` of an item is alerted as **undefined**, but if I use an `if(x==undefined)` syntax it does not work. Can somebody explain what is the problem. Thank you.

```
alert(localStorage["x"]);

if(localStorage["x"]=="undefined"){alert("y");}
```

The top line alerts **undefined**

The bottom line does not alert **y** for me.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706347/javascript-comparing-2-checks-for-localstorage). Use `if ( typeof window.localStorage['x'] != 'undefined' )`

Comment: `'undefined' !== undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't contain the string `"undefined"`, it contains a value of the type `undefined`:

```
if (localStorage["x"] == undefined) { alert("y"); }
```

The value `undefined` is possible to change in older browsers, so good practice is to check the type instead:

```
if (typeof localStorage["x"] == 'undefined') { alert("y"); }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I used this but when I press refresh on the browser it goes from the text I want to undefined. If I clear the localstorage it goes back to message i want then to undefined after i press refresh again

Comment: @daddycardona: Not sure what you are trying to do. It sounds like you are doing something like storing `"undefined"` instead of `undefined`, but it's hard to tell without seeing any code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(typeof( localStorage["x"]) == 'undefined'){alert("y");}
```

OR

```
if( localStorage["x"]  == undefined){alert("y");}
```

OR

```
if( !localStorage["x"] ){alert("y");}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two ways of checking for something being `undefined` are:

```
typeof foo === "undefined"
```

and

```
foo === undefined
```

In the first case, it will be `true` if `foo` was never defined **or** the value of `foo` is `undefined`.

In the second case, it will only be `true` if `foo` was defined (otherwise it'll break) **and** its value is `undefined`.

Checking its value against the string `"undefined"` is not the same at all!

**UPDATE:**

When I said that if you try to perform an operation on an object literal's property that isn't defined, I guess I meant if it's undefined at all, and what I meant was something more like this:

```
obj["x"].toLowerCase()
// or
obj["x"]["y"]
```

where you are attempting to access/operate on something that is originally `undefined`. In this case, simply comparing in an `if` statement should be fine, because of the way object literals report the value...but is very different with normal Javascript variables.

With object literals, if a key (say "x") is not defined, then

```
obj["x"]
```

returns a value of `undefined`, so both the `typeof` and basic `=== undefined` checks will work and be `true`.

The whole difference of not being defined or having a value of `undefined` is different with normal variables.

If you had:

```
var a;
// or
var a = undefined;
```

then both the `typeof` and basic `=== undefined` checks I provided earlier would work and be `true`. But if you never even declared `a`, then only the `typeof` check would work and be `true`. The `=== undefined` check would break.

Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/7npJx/

If you notice in the console, it says `b is not defined` and breaks the `if` statement.

Since you're basically looking at an object literal with `localStorage`, the way to distinguish whether an item is not defined or has a value of `undefined` is to use `in` first. So, you could use:

```
if (!("x" in localStorage)) {
```

to check if "x" is not a defined property at all, and:

```
else if (localStorage["x"] === undefined) {
```

to then check if it is defined but has a value of `undefined`. Then, using:

```
else {
```

would signify that `localStorage["x"]` is both defined and does not have the value `undefined`.

In your code though, it's okay to use the `typeof` or `in` checks (based on what you want to know) because of the way object literals report properties that aren't defined. Using the basic `=== undefined` is also okay, but as **Guffa** pointed out, it's possible for the actual value of `undefined` to be overwritten and then wouldn't work in this comparison. When it comes to normal Javascript variables, `typeof` and `=== undefined` checks aren't the same.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, you have a mistake here: *"In the second case, it will only be true if foo was defined (otherwise it'll break) and its value is undefined."* That is not correct. Reading a property that is not defined returns the value `undefined`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9usJJ/

Comment: @Guffa Thanks for pointing that out. I don't know what I was thinking. I guess I was so focused on how normal variables are reported as `undefined` that I forgot how object literals worked with this...although as soon as you said that, it was a "D'oh, how could I forget" moment. The real problem is comparing to the string `"undefined"`. I updated my answer to hopefully display what I _meant_ in the first place and be more accurate